# Shortcut for deleting a line in dreamweaver?

Tags: dreamweaver

What is the shortcut for deleting the current line where the cursor positioned.
ex: eclipse have crtl+d

Answer (score 4):

To delete line(s)

Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/keyboard-shortcuts.html

Answer (score 3):

There are no direct shortcuts as far as I know but here is a list of commands for dreamweaver.

http://cpaoffers.com/design/dw-shortcuts.php

My typical method to do this is to hit the home > shift+end > del.

Or you could try shift+up or shift+down to select the line above or below and then hit delete.

Answer (score 1):

**Danilo Celic's answer helped me with CS6, just use the second one. Although it's in Japanese, just install and use it.**
If you want to know more: Then, find the installed files in your own
*C:\Users\[your user name]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver CS6\[your CS6 language]\Configuration\Commands*
There you can open the just-installed files and check them. The comments are in Japanese. The code are in Javascript and are easy to read.
There are 5 commands in that file. To use only the "Delete line" function: In CS6, open history panel, go to design mode, do any action like press a key, right click on that action from history panel and record that action. Then you can find the record action in the Commands folder mentioned above, and then you can copy the javascript from the downloaded one into your own recorded action file.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen two extensions that add the delete line functionality:

http://xtnd.us/dreamweaver/codeextras

http://yoropan.com/en/archives/544

I haven't used either one. I've been told that the first one may not work in Dreamweaver CS6, no idea about the other one.  once installed, you should be able to add a keyboard shortcut (Edit -> Preferences, Dreamweaver -> Preferences on Mac) for functionality that you're looking for.

Comment: The first one does not work with CS5 and the second one is in Japanese

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom keyboard shortcut for deleting lines in Dreamweaver.

Dreamweaver uses [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) for its text editor, and this is what handles the Delete Line command, not the traditional Menu system for rebinding most other Dreamweaver commands.

1. Create a Brackets keyboard shortcut configuration file.

   - Windows: `%APPDATA%\Adobe\Dreamweaver CC 2019\en_US\Configuration\Brackets\keymap.json`
   - Mac OS: `~/Library/Application Support/Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2019/en_US/Configuration/Brackets/keymap.json` (untested)
2. Create an override in this file, according to the Brackets [User Key Bindings JSON Data Format](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/User-Key-Bindings). Make sure you use the `-` separator between key names, not `+`.

   ```js
   {
       "overrides": {
           "Ctrl-E": "edit.deletelines"
       }
   }
   ```
3. Rebind any conflicting keyboard shortcuts in Dreamweaver. In my `Ctrl`+`E` example above, it collides with Quick Edit.

   1. In Dreamweaver, go to Edit → Keyboard Shortcuts.
   2. Make a new Set if you're using the default Dreamweaver Standard Set.
   3. Find the command you want to change. Quick Edit is in the Code Editing section.
   4. Highlight the shortcut you want to modify.
   5. If you want to unbind that shortcut, click the `-` button.
   6. Otherwise, rebind that shortcut by typing the new shortcut in the Press Key field, and then clicking Change.
   7. Click OK to save your changes.
   8. If your change is not persisted, you can usually fix this by editing the following files.

      - `%APPDATA%\Adobe\Dreamweaver CC 2019\en_US\Configuration\Menus\Custom Sets\*.xml`
      - `%APPDATA%\Adobe\Dreamweaver CC 2019\en_US\Configuration\Menus\menus.xml`
4. Restart Dreamweaver for your new Brackets keyboard shortcuts to be read.

To bind other commands besides Delete Line, see the full [Brackets Shortcuts](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Brackets-Shortcuts) command ID column.

I used these steps with Adobe Dreamweaver 2019 (19.2) on Windows.